# Changing the color of a cell in a html table when I hover over it

Tags: html, html-table

I have looked through all the answers posted but I cant seem to get this code to work correctly.  I am trying to get the individual cell to change color when I hover over it, but I don't have access to the .css with the service we are using.  I am being forced to drop an HTML code box that I can paste my code into specific to the element I am changing, but not the entire .css file...just that element.

Here is my code.  Any help in getting the background to change to #ff0000 and the Text to change to #000000 when I roll over the cell would be greatly appreciated.

(It is ultimately my intent to add a >a href for each of the cells as well, but I am trying to do this one step at a time.  The >a href will (I hope) add the selected cell to a shopping cart.)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xml:lang="en" lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<title></title>

<style type="text/css">
body {
      background: #000;   
}
#wrap {
     margin: 0 auto; /* margin 0 auto will center that box in your document */
     width: 780px; /*size of your box*/
     background: #000;
     text-align: center; /* everything will be written in that box will be centered horizontally*/
     }
</style>
<div id="wrap">
  <table width="780">
     <tr>
        <td align="center">
<table border=1>
  <tbody>
    <!-- Results table headers -->
    <tr>
      <th>Messages Per Month</th>
      <th>1 Month Pricing</th>
      <th>3 Month Pricing</th>
      <th>12 Month Pricing</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>500</td>
      <td>$14.95/Month</td>
      <td>$12.95/Month</td>
      <td>$9.95/Month</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1,000</td>
      <td>$24.95/Month</td>
      <td>$20.95/Month</td>
      <td>$17.95/Month</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1,500</td>
      <td>$37.95/Month</td>
      <td>$31.95/Month</td>
      <td>$26.95/Month</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2,000</td>
      <td>$49.95/Month</td>
      <td>$41.95/Month</td>
      <td>$35.95/Month</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2,500</td>
      <td>$62.95/Month</td>
      <td>$52.95/Month</td>
      <td>$44.95/Month</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5,000</td>
      <td>$119.95/Month</td>
      <td>Not Available</td>
      <td>Not Available</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>7,500</td>
      <td>$179.95/Month</td>
      <td>Not Available</td>
      <td>Not Available</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>10,000</td>
      <td>$219.95/Month</td>
      <td>Not Available</td>
      <td>Not Available</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
        </td>
     </tr>
   </table>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by “I am being forced to drop an HTML code box that I can paste my code into specific to the element I am changing”?  Do you mean that you can only create a `style` attribute for an HTML element? Show us an example of what you *can* do, in terms of resulting HTML and CSS code.

Answer (score 12):

In CSS:

```
td:hover {
  background-color: #ff0000;
  color: #000000;
}
```

Or you can use JavaScript/jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("td").hover(
    function() {
      $(this).css('background-color', '#ff0000');
      $(this).css('color', '#000000');
    }, 
    function() {
      $(this).css('background-color', 'none');
      $(this).css('color', 'black'); // or whatever your original color was
    }
  );
});
```

Comment: The td: hover {background-color: #ff0000; color: #000000;} does what I want it to do for my table headers...but what about the individual cells in the table?

Comment: `td: hover {background-color: #ff0000; color: #000000;}`  should be working on the cells. Do you also want something to happen to the headers when you hover over them?

Answer (score 1):

CSS: `td:hover, th:hover { background:#ff0000; color:#000; }`

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the cell data with a div (class="cell_hvr") and a link around the content.

```
.cell_hvr {
    padding: 2px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.cell_hvr a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.cell_hvr a:hover {
    background-color: red;
}

<div class="cell_hvr"><a href="#" target="_blank"> (Your content) </a></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by giving each cell a class

```
<td class="a">..</td>
```

and then styling it

```
<style>
  td.a { background-color:#ff0000; }
  td.a:hover { background-color:#000000; }
</style>
```

Comment: Is the "a" in RA's example intended to define or imply an HTML "a" tag, such as a hyperlink, or is it just a random class name?

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the JavaScript version of the answer to this question. But, I am not using JQuery..

I have 
`oCell = newRow.insertCell();
oCell.style.background =  tintTest(myCounts[i]);`

myCounts is just an array holding an Int..

but now i just wanted to add the hover background color to my current oCell before smashing it in line and moving on with the loop...... 
So I found the code below as the only checked answer in a stream of 'can't be done'.. just not sure if this would even help me.

```
var css = 'table td:hover{ background-color: #00ff00 }';
var style = document.createElement('style');

if (style.styleSheet) {
    style.styleSheet.cssText = css;
} else {
    style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
}

document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style);
```

EDIT!!! I just found out my issue (I hope the code snip helps with yours still)  I tried to add the hover in CSS and it just isn't supported at all.