# HTML change table cell background AND text font colour on hover AT THE SAME TIME

Tags: html

NEWBIE: I'm currently working on a 1and1 website. I want different boxes on a main page which all link to different sub-pages. Each box comprises an image and "category" text below image. I used tables within a table to create the boxes because of the borders. I have also added a hover effect so when you mouse-over any of those boxes/tables, the background changes colour.  What I would like to do is have the text change colour AT THE SAME TIME as the box changing colour.  I should point out that I know ABSOLUTELY NOTHING about CSS and very little about HTML, so a working example would make my day! Thanks in advance.  Here's what I've cobbled together so far:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="10" style="width: 685px;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
            <table bgcolor="#F7F7F3" border="1" bordercolor="#89A6A1" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3" onmouseout="this.bgColor='#f7f7f3'" onmouseover="this.bgColor='#89A6A1'; this.style.color='black'" style="width: 100%; color: black;">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                        <p><a href=""><img a="" alt="Awaiting Image" src="" style="width: 100%; max-width: 219px; height:auto; horizontal-align: center;" /></a></p>

                        <p>&nbsp;</p>

                        <p><strong><span style="color:#89A6A1;">Category</span></strong></p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            </td>
            <td>
            <table bgcolor="#f7f7f3" border="1" bordercolor="#89A6A1" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3" onmouseout="this.bgColor='#f7f7f3'" onmouseover="this.bgColor='#89A6A1'" style="width: 100%;">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                        <p><a href=""><img a="" alt="Awaiting Image" src="" style="width: 100%; max-width: 219px; height:auto; horizontal-align: center;" /></a></p>

                        <p>&nbsp;</p>

                        <p><strong><span style="color:#89A6A1;">Category</span></strong></p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            </td>
            <td>
            <table bgcolor="#f7f7f3" border="1" bordercolor="#89A6A1" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3" onmouseout="this.bgColor='#f7f7f3'" onmouseover="this.bgColor='#89A6A1'" style="width: 100%;">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                        <p><a href=""><img a="" alt="Awaiting Image" src="" style="width: 100%; max-width: 219px; height:auto; horizontal-align: center;" /></a></p>

                        <p>&nbsp;</p>

                        <p><strong><span style="color:#89A6A1;">Category</span></strong></p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

just use color:green for example. You should try and keep your styles seperate from your html, some of the attributes you are using on the table tags are deprecated, have a look here [w3Schools Table tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_table.asp)

```css
td:hover{background:#F00;color:#0f0;}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>cell 1</td>
    <td> cell 2</td>
   </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: Copied your snippet and can see it working, but don't know where to put the hover bit into my code - it comes out as actual text on the webpage wherever I put it!

Comment: mak a file in the same folder and call it style.css. put `td:hover{background:#F00;color:#0f0;}` in that file. In between the opening <head> and closing </head> tags in your html document put `<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />` and you've now linked a stylesheet to you html document.

Comment: The website I'm using is a 1and1 website package that enables you to create stuff using drag & drop elements i.e, text box, image box, table, column etc., without knowledge of html, but when you say "make a file in the same folder and call it style.css" I'm lost. I don't have folders on my website.  I am able to upload images, so would I do the same for a style.css?

Comment: you do have folders somewhere on your website. best to go to 1&1 support and ask them as i've never used them. As a very last option, one that I don't recommend, you could add it inline to each td like `<td onmouseover="this.style.color='red';this.style.background='green'" onmouseout="this.style.color='';this.style.background=''">Hover me</td>`

Comment: Still no joy after hours of practice! Thanks for help. Will try and learn about css and do it properly to save cumbersome changes in the future. With little knowledge, it's an uphill struggle!

Comment: what browser you using ? click on a td in your browser and inspect the element, that will tell you where the css that affects the file is located. do you have a control panel with 1 & 1 ? look for the file manager option.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem with the current code is that the cells contain various elements that have their own text (content) color: links and `span` elements with `color` property set on them. Setting  text color on a cell (directly or by setting it on the enclosing table) cannot override such things.

The code should probably be refactored (rewritten), but here is a minimal change to fix this specific issue. I have removed the `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` attributes, since it is easier and more robust to set things up using just the `:hover` pseudo-class. The point here is to set text color for all descendants of a `td` element (all elements inside it), and since color is set on `span` with inline styles, with `style=...` attributes, an `!important` specifier is needed to override it.

```css
table table td:hover {
  background: #89A6A1;
}
table table td:hover * {
  color: black !important;
}
```

```html
<table border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="10" style="width: 685px;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
            <table bgcolor="#F7F7F3" border="1" bordercolor="#89A6A1" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3" style="width: 100%; color: black;">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                        <p><a href=""><img a="" alt="Awaiting Image" src="" style="width: 100%; max-width: 219px; height:auto; horizontal-align: center;" /></a></p>

                        <p>&nbsp;</p>

                        <p><strong><span style="color:#89A6A1;">Category</span></strong></p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            </td>
            <td>
            <table bgcolor="#f7f7f3" border="1" bordercolor="#89A6A1" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3" style="width: 100%;">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                        <p><a href=""><img a="" alt="Awaiting Image" src="" style="width: 100%; max-width: 219px; height:auto; horizontal-align: center;" /></a></p>

                        <p>&nbsp;</p>

                        <p><strong><span style="color:#89A6A1;">Category</span></strong></p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            </td>
            <td>
            <table bgcolor="#f7f7f3" border="1" bordercolor="#89A6A1" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3" style="width: 100%;">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                        <p><a href=""><img a="" alt="Awaiting Image" src="" style="width: 100%; max-width: 219px; height:auto; horizontal-align: center;" /></a></p>

                        <p>&nbsp;</p>

                        <p><strong><span style="color:#89A6A1;">Category</span></strong></p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: That's great Jukka. Can you tell me where I put the code that starts with table table td: hover? Does it just get put right at the beginning of the other code?

Comment: @JLO, you can put it between `<style>` and `</style>` tags in the `head` part of the page, e.g. right after the `title` element.

Comment: Let me explain. I dragged & dropped a table element that comes shipped with website package onto webpage. I then get a blank basic table for starters. I clicked on html button which gets you 'behind' the table & stripped out html so I'm left with a blank box to put my own code in.  No 'head' or 'title' in the box - nothing. I pasted the code into the box. Saved it & closed the box. That's it. Your example works great in this forum, but when I paste the hover bit in at the beginning of my code, everything goes wrong! Sorry for troubling you, but I need a self-contained solution inside the box.

Answer (score -1):

Here goes the sample. This is taken from this thread 
[Changing the color of a cell in a html table when I hover over it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11731269/changing-the-color-of-a-cell-in-a-html-table-when-i-hover-over-it?rq=1)
and modified:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<style type="text/css">
.styledTable td:hover {
  background-color: #ff0000;
  color: blue;
}
</style>

<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrap">
<table class="styledTable" border=1>
  <tbody>
    <!-- Results table headers -->
    <tr>
      <th>Messages Per Month</th>
      <th>1 Month Pricing</th>
      <th>3 Month Pricing</th>
      <th>12 Month Pricing</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>500</td>
      <td>$14.95/Month</td>
      <td>$12.95/Month</td>
      <td>$9.95/Month</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1,000</td>
      <td>$24.95/Month</td>
      <td>$20.95/Month</td>
      <td>$17.95/Month</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<hr/>
<table border=1>
  <tbody>
    <!-- Results table headers -->
    <tr>
      <th>Messages Per Month</th>
      <th>1 Month Pricing</th>
      <th>3 Month Pricing</th>
      <th>12 Month Pricing</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>500</td>
      <td>$14.95/Month</td>
      <td>$12.95/Month</td>
      <td>$9.95/Month</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1,000</td>
      <td>$24.95/Month</td>
      <td>$20.95/Month</td>
      <td>$17.95/Month</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1,500</td>
      <td>$37.95/Month</td>
      <td>$31.95/Month</td>
      <td>$26.95/Month</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here we have two tables. One with the style applied and the other one with no style. The key difference between the two tables is the *class=styledTable* attribute in the first table. Then, in the *css* section of the HTML, we have a style that can be applied to all *td* elements within tables that have a class named *styledTable*. The *:hover* part means that the style should be applied when the mouse hovers over the element:

```
.styledTable td:hover{
  background-color: #ff0000;
  color: blue;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Copied your entire code to see how it looked and when I viewed the webpage, nothing changed colour. I know NOTHING about CSS although I do get the concept of creating some code and then referencing that code so you don't have to keep doing it, but that's it I'm afraid!

Comment: How did you copied the code? Copy all of the code into a file named Sample.html, then open Sample.html with your browser and hover over the cells in the first table. When you move your mouse over a cell in the first table, it's background change to red and the font color changes to blue. It works perfectly fine.

Comment: Copied code into file as instructed. Opened Sample.html and yes it works absolutely fine. Put it on website and no hover colour changes. Must be 1and1 website package. Will have to revisit, I've tried so many ways. Will give up for now! Thank you for your help though.